# How to find sum without exceeding a limit

Tags: java, list

I need to calculate the sum of the withdrawal without exceeding the limit given.THere can be multipkle withrawals. The sum of all withdrawals should not exceed the limit. The output of the function is the customer name when the limit exceeds. What I have so far lööks like the below snippet. I am not sure how to go further. I am getting an error at b.amount Cannot resolve symbol 'amount'.

```
public String method(List<Customer> customers, amoutLimit){
 customers.stream().map((a,b)-> {
                if ((a.amount + b.amount)> creditLimit){
                 return a.transactionId;   
                }
              return Collections.emptyList();
            }).toList();
   
}
class Customer (
        String name, String email, int amount, String TransactionId){}

}
```

The input can look like `Arrays.asList("John,Doe,john@doe.com,200,TrId1", "John,Doe,john@doe.com,2,TrId2"), 200`. This should output TrId2 since it is when the second withdrawal happens the limit of 200 is exceeded.

Comment: do you mean a withdrawal may not be for more than a specific amount, or the sum of all withdrawals may not exceed a certain amount?

Comment: Where do you want to apply the limit? Just compare the number. `result < withdrawal` or similar. Without context it's not possible to answer. And you do know about the `>` and `<` operators and how to use an `if`, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a custom collector.

Example:

```
class Accumulator {
    final int limit;
    int sum;
    String lastId;
    boolean done;

    public static Collector<Customer,Accumulator,String> collector(int limit) {
        return Collector.of(() -> new Accumulator(limit),
                        Accumulator::process, 
                        Accumulator::combine,
                        Accumulator::finish);
    }

    public Accumulator(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void process(Customer cust) {
        if (done) {
            // nothing
        } else if (sum + cust.amount > limit) {
            done = true;
        } else {
            sum += cust.amount;
            lastId = cust.TransactionId;
        }
    }

    public Accumulator combine(Accumulator other) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot combine");
    }

    public String finish() {
        return lastId;
    }
}
```

...

```
    int limit = 200;
    String transId = customers.stream()
            .collect(Accumulator.collector(limit));
    System.out.println(transId);
```

Looks like overkill though.

UPDATE:

Let's not get carried away: here a simpler solution:

```
public String method(List<Customer> customers, int limit) {
    String lastId = null;
    int sum = 0;
    for (Customer  cust: customers) {
        if (sum + cust.amount > limit) {
            break;
        } else {
            sum += cust.amount;
            lastId = cust.TransactionId;
        }
    }
    return lastId;
}
```